# items scrapy in sqlite3 : Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, scrapy

I'm trying to store the items in a sqlite3 database.
I have generated all the items..

Here is my storage code in my pipelines:

```
con = None  # db connection
class StoreInDBPipeline(object):

# constructeur
def __init__(self):
    self.createBD()
    self.dropFactureTable()
    self.createFactureTable()

# implémenter dans la classe Pipeline et renvoyer une exception dict, Item ou DropItem
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.storeInDb(item)
    return item

# insertion
def storeInDb(self, item):
    self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO Facture(numDocument, dateFacture, datePaiement, typeFacture, montantTTC, lienFacture ) VALUES( ?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                     (item['numDocument'], item['dateFacture'], item['datePaiement'], item['typeFacture'], item['montantTTC'], item['lienFacture']))
    log.msg("Item stored in db", level=log.DEBUG)
    self.con.commit()

# creer la BD / cursor
def createBD(self):
    self.con = lite.connect('BD_Facture.db')
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()

# contrepartie du constructeur (destructeur) fermer la connexion à la BD
def __del__(self):
    self.closeDB()

# creer la table
def createFactureTable(self):
    self.cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Facture(numDocument INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, dateFacture TEXT, datePaiement TEXT,typeFacture TEXT, montantTTC TEXT , lienFacture TEXT)')

# supprime la table dans la BD
def dropFactureTable(self):
    self.cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Facture")

# fermer la connexion à la BD
def closeDB(self):
    self.con.close()
```

But during storage, I get this error :

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably
>   unsupported type.

Comment: Without knowing how you’re calling it or what the value of `item` is, it’s hard to say what the issue might be. Try printing the `repr` of the values to see what you’re passing to the `INSERT`:

    `print([repr(item[x]) for x in ["numDocument", "dateFacture", "datePaiment", "typeFacture", "montantTTC", "lienFacture"]])`

Comment: The screenshot shows a list containing the string representation of a list of strings, so it looks like you’re not passing it a single string. You should double-check the call to `storeInDb` to see what you’re passing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to make a 'for' in each dictionary :

```
for num,dateF,dateP,type,mont in zip(item['numDocument'],item['dateFacture'],item['datePaiement'],item['typeFacture'],item['montantTTC']):
        self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO Facture(numDocument, dateFacture, datePaiement, typeFacture, montantTTC) VALUES( ?,?,?,?,?)", (num,dateF,dateP,type,mont))

self.con.commit()
```